# NullPointerException при инициализации CalendarView

Tags: java, android, исключения

Возникает *npe* ошибка. Если я правильно понимаю, ошибки данного вида возникают, если кто-то пытается обратиться по null-ссылке. Ругается на разные строчки кода
[image: NullPointerException]

```
01-13 12:26:22.206 10621-10621/com.jaloveast1k.topbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.jaloveast1k.topbook, PID: 10621
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity$MonthsPagerAdapter.refreshAllLists(MainActivity.java:1262)
     at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity.selectTab(MainActivity.java:978)
     at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity.access$2400(MainActivity.java:50)
     at com.jaloveast1k.topbook.MainActivity$TabClicker.onClick(MainActivity.java:925)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

вот код

```
        public void refreshAllLists() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int offsetForItem = calcOffsetForItem(i);
            final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) views.get(i).findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
            int m = DateTimesHelper.monthByOffset(offsetForItem);
            int y = DateTimesHelper.yearByOffset(offsetForItem);
            calendarView.renewCurrentMonth(m, y);

            TextView title = (TextView) views.get(i).findViewById(R.id.calendar_title);
            title.setText(DateTimesHelper.makeCalendarTitle(offsetForItem, MainActivity.this));

            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) views.get(i).findViewById(R.id.calendarLayout);
            parent.removeAllViews();
            Month month = DBWorker.getInstance().getTasksForMonth(offsetForItem);
            ArrayList<Task> currArr = month.tasks;
            for (int j = 0; j < currArr.size(); j++) {
                View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_calendar, null);
                Task t = currArr.get(j);
                TextView text = (TextView) subView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_task);
                TextView time = (TextView) subView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_task_day);
                text.setText(t.getText());
                if (t.isFinished()) {
                    text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_task_done));
                    text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                time.setText(month.dates.get(j));
                parent.addView(subView);
            }
        }
    }
```

вот 1262 строка кода на которую ругается

```
final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) views.get(i).findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

вот что показывает дебагер
[image: дебагер]

Comment: Приложите стактрейс кодом, а не картинкой. Плюс еще код приложите, на котором сваливается. Код выложите из класса MainActivity

Comment: Пройдитесь дебагом по своему коду и найдите строчку кода которая выбрасывает данный эксепшен.

Comment: Выложите логи текстом и приложите 1262 строку и код, коим вы инициализируете объекты, пользуемые в этой строке. И сократите код в активити - его у вас там слишком много

Comment: строчку 1262 пометьте в коде как-нибудь

Comment: У вас `views` или `views.get(i)` равно `null`. Но что именно - знаете только вы.

Comment: Либо views null, либо views.get(i) null. Дебагером пройдись и посмотри, что именно у тебя null и пойми, почему у тебя это null

Comment: спасибо сейчас посмотрю

Comment: не знаю правильно ли я работаю с этим дебагером, но у меня там много элементов null или я не там копаю(

Comment: как в дебагере найти views или views.get(i) чему равно, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вам не нужен дебаггер чтобы знать что что-то из этого `null`. Вам надо посмотреть код, где вы ваш список/карту создаёте и наполняете данными. Ошибка где-то там.

Comment: ок, посмотрю сейчас )

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я все еще не решил данную проблему, вы можете как нибудь мне помочь?